# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to +0}\frac{1}{x}{\int^{2022x}_{0}{t\,\sqrt{|\cos(\frac{1}{t})|} \,dt}}$ without L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, limits-without-lhopital

My problem is to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x \to +0}\frac{1}{x}{\int^{2022x}_{0}{t\,\sqrt{|\cos(\frac{1}{t})|}\,dt}}$$

I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Even when you're completely stumped, you can provide useful context. If this is a textbook exercise, tell us the topic(s) covered so far that seem relevant. If it's an online challenge or contest, give the intended audience. Sometimes, just "thinking out loud" about things you know can get you going, and it keeps others from explaining things you already understand. ... In any case, the more you can show that you're personally invested in finding a solution, the more likely it is that others will become invested in helping you with the search.

Comment: Consider $|\cos(\frac{1}{t})|\le 1$

Comment: I can't integrate over function which has modulus. This is from quite tough last year online contest.

Comment: The function in the integral is continuous at $t=0$ (provided we set its value $0$ at $t=0$) Apply the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Are you aware of fundamental theorem of calculus? If yes then use the substitution $2022x=u$ in limit operation and then use fundamental theorem of calculus. Meanwhile please provide additional relevant context (including source of problem and any attempt based on discussion in comments).

Answer (score 2):

HINT: the inequality $0 \le |\cos\big(\frac{1}{t}\big)| \le 1$ holds for all real positive $t$. Thus, for each real positive $x$, the following string of inequalities hold:
$$0 \ \le \ \frac{1}{x}\times\left|\int^{2022x}_{0}{t\sqrt{\left|\cos\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}\ dt}\right| \ \le \ \frac{1}{x}\times\left|\int^{2022x}_0 t \ dt\right|$$
$$=\frac{1}{x}\times1011x^2 \ = \ 1011x.$$

Can you take it from here.